# Filtering WebSocket Connections (Reject Unknown Clients)

Tags: php

I am running a PHP WebSockets server (React PHP + Ratchet) and I have my own client application that will communicate with the server.

The problem is that ANY WebSockets client application can connect to this server.

I am looking for some thoughts to implement a method to reject connections from all clients but my client-application ?

*One idea I had it to include an additional key field in the handshake headers ? I understand an hacker could reproduce this easily but many others wont bother doing it.*

Comment: "I understand an hacker could reproduce this easily but many others wont bother doing it" --- why to bother then? Anyone experienced enough to implement a ws client can break your "protection".

Comment: I meant my thought is not flawless and I look forward to hear from the gurus

Comment: well, my point is: you cannot do anything with it

Answer (score 0):

Put the encryption of a (key + date time + ip) in the header.
On the server decrypt it and check that the connection is made ate the specified time with the specified ip.
I think its not too bad. What do you think?